# Convert array dictionary to a dictionary python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I want to convert this array to dictionary without the word array.

`{1: array([[ 38.13823661,  48.52341785]]), 2: array([[ 19.60433883, 45.63071969]])}`

Comment: How did you get `array` in first place?

Comment: Can you include your solution that you tried

Comment: Please put additional information regarding the question as to what you are trying to do? What have you tried? and if possible code snippet of the issue.

Comment: are the array objects from numpy?

Comment: This dictionary is the execution of a mobility model of random way point. In order to integrate the code to the map (marker), I should convert the execution to a dictionary, like this: {1: [x1,y1], [x2,y2]}

Comment: RichSmith, yes it's from numpy

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
output = {}
for key in originalDict:
    output[key] = originalDict[key].tolist()
```

Where originalDict is the dictionary you showed us, with numpy arrays.

There's probably a neater way of writing it but it should work.

EDIT: with regards to your comment, if you just need the inner list, then index the first element of each value in the dict after converting it, like this:

```
    output = {}
    for key in originalDict:
        output[key] = originalDict[key].tolist()[0]
```

Comment: {1: [[49.90163153016479, 87.66985363280287]], 2: [[49.90163153016479, 87.66985363280287]]}
I must remove [] like this:  {1: [ , ], [ , ]}

Comment: @Anita see my edit, that should give you what you're after

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. It work, and when I like to see all the list I remove the [0]
Thank you a lot